# Sean Carroll GR - Ex.3.6 (b) & (c)

Tags: homework-and-exercises, general-relativity, metric-tensor, geodesics

I'm working in the newtonian limit of GR with the metric

$$
ds^2 = -(1+2\Phi)dt^2 + (1-2\Phi)dr^2 +r^2d\theta^2+r^2sin^2\theta\;d\phi^2
$$

where

$$\Phi = -\frac{GM}{r}.$$

We are first asked to compare the time dilation between two different radii R1 and R2 which was straightforward. My problem is with (b) and (c):

(b) Solve for a geodesic corresponding to a circular orbit around the equator of the Earth ($\theta = \pi/2$). What is $d\phi/dt$?

(c) How much proper time elapses while a satellite at Radius R1 completes one orbit? (to first order in $\Phi$).

I can find the Christoffel symbols, but I don't understand how we arrive at an equation which is not degenerate. I always end up with $0\; \partial\phi/\partial t = 0$ which is obviously not the desired answer.

I don't even know where to begin for part (c)

Edit: Thinking about it some more, when we set the radius($r=R$) and angle ($\theta = \pi/2$) constant the metric reduces to $$
ds^2 = -(1+2\Phi)dt^2 +R^2d\phi^2
$$
Is this not correct?

Edit2: Using this and calculating the connection and plugging the geodesic equation I compute 
$$
\frac{d^2\phi}{d\tau^2} = -\frac{1}{R^2}\frac{d\Phi}{d\phi}
$$
With the only non-zero geodesic component being 
$$
\frac{d^2\phi}{d\tau^2}+\frac{1}{R^2}\frac{\partial\Phi}{\partial{\phi}}\left(\frac{\partial{t}}{\partial{\tau}}\right)^2 = 0
$$

What am I doing wrong here?

Edit 3:

Okay so $\frac{\partial{\Phi}}{\partial{\phi}} = 0$ hence $\frac{d^2\phi}{d\tau^2} = 0$ which means $\frac{d\phi}{d\tau} = \omega_c$.

Now I'm still not sure how to go about part (c). Is it the period of the function I just derived?

Comment: Publish the equations you got.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't comment yet, so I have to offer this hint as an answer. Have you tried calculating $\frac{d\Phi}{d\phi}$?

Comment: Oh wait, the field is constant over angles so $\frac{d\Phi}{d\phi} = 0$ which means $\frac{d\phi}{dt} = const$. Does that sound correct?

Comment: Yes, you seemed to have figured it out.